# Bind a run box command to start the application

Tags: .net, winforms, installation, command

I have created an installer for my windows application using C#. After installing the application i want my users to type in a command in Run box dialog and start the application from there. How i can achieve this ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install your application in one of the directories that are in `PATH`. This way, when the user types the `exe` name in the Run box, the application will launch

Comment: be noted that the PATH is client-side; i.e. if you install on other PC, the PC has to set the PATH variable too.

Comment: I'm installing it in "C:\Program Files\bla bla\bla.exe" is that correct ?

Comment: @Umar: Then you should add `C:\Program Files\Bla Bla\ ` to the `PATH` environment variable

Answer (score 1):

They will need to enter the full path to the application, e.g. `%ProgramFiles%\MyFolder\MyApp.exe`.

Comment: But i would like to give the option of only type "MyApp" in run box.

Comment: If they are using Vista or Windows 7, they can press the Start button and type the app name.  If you definitely want to do it in the Run box, you will need to extend the PATH environment variable, as mentioned in the other answer.  Not the best idea, but if you definitely need to have that functionality, that's the way to do it

Comment: What are the pros and cons of setting this variable as you mentioned it's not the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your application in **App Paths**:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\
    MyApp.exe
        (Default) = <full-path-to>\MyApp.exe
```

See [Finding an Application Executable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ee872121.aspx#app_exe) for more technical details.
Raymond Chen'd blog post [How is it possible to run Wordpad by just typing its name even though it isn't on the PATH?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/25/10189298.aspx) also discusses this very subject.